# JSF 1.2: How to open a new window and catch the fact that user tried it

Tags: javascript, jsf, jsf-1.2

I'd like to open a new browser window, with everything hidden. Also I'd like to know that the user has initiated the action and record in the backend using JSF.

From reading internet, it looks like I can use window.open but then JSF is totally bypassed. Also I'd like to pass a value of a bean into the javascript as well.

Is this a pipe dream ? Can I do it with JSF 1.2 ? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just pass it as a request parameter on the URL.

```
<h:outputLink value="#" onclick="window.open('popup.jsf?foo=#{bean.foo}');">
    popup
</h:outputLink>
```

You could make `foo` parameter a managed property of the bean associated with the popup page.

E.g.

```
<managed-property>
    <property-name>foo</property-name>
    <value>#{param.foo}</value>
</managed-property>
```

with

```
public class PopupBean {

    private String foo;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() throws IOException {
        doSomethingWith(foo);
        youCouldLogHereAsWellThatPopupIsBeenOpened();
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().redirect("http://other.com/report");
    }

    // ...
}
```

*(the `@PostConstruct` method is invoked after bean's construction and managed propery injection)*

Comment: Ok so I can pass param to javascript if it is managed propery, How can I tell that output link is clicked ? This looks like init has been triggered during bean creation not user action.

Comment: Why do you think that the bean can be created by other means than an user action? Is it been used in other pages? Then change it accordingly so that it's only created when the popup page is been requested. I.e. do not bind the bean to other pages.

Comment: The page I am popping up is outside the JSF application. It displays a report based on some parameters passed as a get method. The parameters are set in the web page I display by the user. I need to know that the report has been requested and set things in motion on the JSF side. I am probably missing something.

Comment: You should not have omitted that detail from the question. I'll update the answer. Note the `ExternalContext#redirect()` line to redirect the request to the report.

Comment: Balus, one more change, can it redirect using a post ?

Comment: That would require a lot of changes. You'd need a form with a submit button and `target="_blank"` (so `window.open()` is out of question) and you should use a HTTP 307 redirect, but that would in all decent webbrowsers rise an annoying security warning.